# avplayerviewcontroller slider control not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view controller to which i am adding a AVPlayerViewController. 
I am trying to play both audio as well as video on this controller. It plays both without any issues.

However if i try to drag the slider to a different position, nothing happens and the video/audio starts playing from beginning. 
But if i click the default 15 second slider its works, the slider move ahead/backward by 15 seconds!

Do i need to handle the slider event specifically? If so is there an example?
This is what i have on my viewwillAppear so far

```
    let mediaURL = URL(string:fileMediaUrl!)
    if let murl=mediaURL {
        self.avPlayer=AVPlayer(url:murl)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player=self.avPlayer
    }

    self.addChildViewController(avPlayerViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(avPlayerViewController.view)
    avPlayerViewController.view.frame=self.view.frame
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: avPlayer?.currentItem)
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(PlayMediaViewController.avPlayer.rate), options: [.new], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
    avPlayer?.play()
```

Comment: All of the onscreen controls should work out of the box. What are you doing in your observers?

Comment: Thats what i thought too. So hoping its just a simulator thing. I am trying to capture the rate and it works fine too!. i will have to try running this on a phone and see what happens.